# Default class inheritance access

Tags: c++, inheritance

Suppose I have a base and derived class:

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void Do();
}

class Derived:Base
{
    public:
    virtual void Do();
}

int main()
{
    Derived sth;
    sth.Do(); // calls Derived::Do OK
    sth.Base::Do(); // ERROR; not calls Based::Do 
}
```

as seen I wish to access Base::Do through Derived. I get a compile error as "class Base in inaccessible" however when I declare Derive as

```
class Derived: public Base
```

it works ok.

I have read default inheritance access is public, then why I need to explicitly declare public inheritance here?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You might have read something incomplete or misleading. To quote Bjarne Stroustrup from "The C++ programming Language", fourth Ed., p. 602:

> In a `class`, members are by default `private`; in a `struct`, members
>   are by default `public` (§16.2.4).

This also holds for members inherited without access level specifier.

A widespread convention is, to use struct only for organization of pure data members. You correctly used a `class` to model and implement object behaviour.

Comment: @Prasoon Taken out of context you are right, but the context established by the title and the code clearly is "class" and not "struct".

Answer (score 115):

From standard docs, *11.2.2*

> In the absence of an access-specifier for a base class, **public** is assumed when the derived class is defined with the
>   *class-key* **struct** and **private** is assumed when the class is defined with the *class-key* **class**.

So, for `struct`s the default is `public` and for `class`es, the default is `private`...

Examples from the standard docs itself,

`class D3 : B { / ... / }; // B private by default`

`struct D6 : B { / ... / }; // B public by default`

Answer (score 11):

The default inheritance level (in absence of an access-specifier for a base class )for `class` in C++ is private. [For `struct` it is public]

`class Derived:Base`

`Base` is privately inherited so you cannot do `sth.Base::Do();` inside `main()` because `Base::Do()` is private inside `Derived`

Answer (score 7):

The default type of the inheritance is private.
In your code,

> class B:A

is nothing but

> class B: private A