# Accessing and changing parent values from subclass instances

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, parent, subclass

I am a beginner and tryed to find an answer on this website but I was not able to figure out how to solve my specific C++ OOP problem.

Short: I want to access and change values of a parent class from subclass instances, but somehow my approach seems not to be working.

Example: There are many `Car` instances in my program (created with new construct). If one of the `Car` objects detects a collision, all `Car` instances should inverse their movement. The `Car` that registered the collision should call the parents' `ChangeSpeed` method or change the `speed` value directly.

Problem: the speed variable seems not to be updated. Is there something wrong with this particular code/ approach or do I have to search for my problem somewhere else?

```
// SpeedControl.h ------------------------------
class SpeedControl
{
public:
    void ChangeSpeed(int);
protected:
    int speed;
};

class Car:
        public SpeedControl
{
public:
    void MoveCar();
    void DetectCollision();

private:
    int position;
};


// SpeedControl.cpp ------------------------------
#include SpeedControl.h

SpeedControl::SpeedControl(void)
{
    speed = 10;
}

SpeedControl::~SpeedControl(void)
{
}

SpeedControl::ChangeSpeed(int _value)
{
    speed *= _value;
}


// Car.cpp ------------------------------
#include SpeedControl.h

Car::Car(void)
{
    position = 100;
}

Car::~Car(void)
{
}

Car::MoveCar()
{
    position += speed; // speed should be accessible?
}

Car::DetectCollision()
{
    speed *= (-1); // inverse speed variable in parent class to inverse direction of ALL cars
    // alternative:
    // ChangeSpeed(-1); // call parent function to inverse speed

}
```

Comment: change *class Car:SpeedControl* to *class Car: public SpeedControl* (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811424/default-class-inheritance-access)

Comment: You should also stay *what exactly is not working*. In this case, it's as thang suggested, private inheritance.

Comment: you've changed the question now.  speed is now accessible.  remove that comment.  inheritance is **the wrong construct to use here**.  you want aggregation.  create SpeedControl as a separate object.  delare a (smart)pointer to it in Car.  have all your cars share the same SpeedControl.

Comment: specified my problem in the text, sorry. also my "SpeedControl" was already public, I only forgot to type it in.

Comment: so then speed is accessible.  what is with that comment that implies that speed is not accessible.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem where the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a `GetSpeed()` in your `SpeedControl` class, which returns the current speed.

Then you can use this in MoveCar function:

```
ChangeSpeed(GetSpeed() + GetSpeed());  // Assuming you want to double the speed.
```

and in your collision:

```
ChangeSpeed(-GetSpeed());
```

Alternatively, you could make "ChangeSpeed" a multiplication rather than an addition.

Comment: this wouldn't work... because the car class won't have access to GetSpeed.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state *what* exactly is wrong with your code, but from glancing on it, you're using `private` inheritance, which hides all parent's members from derived classes.

```
class Child : public Parent { };
```

The line above will ensure that the Parent members are accessible from Child.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to misunderstand inheritance. What you need is a static variable.

Define static int speed in Car class. You can drop SpeedControl class.