# writing a case insenstive string class

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading

I'm reading Herb Sutter's book *Exceptional C++*, and in the second item you need to write a case insensitive string class **ci_string** with the following behavior:

```
#include <assert.h>

ci_string s("AbCdE");

// case insensitive
//
assert(s == "abcde");
assert(s == "ABCDE");
// still case-preserving, of course
//
assert(strcmp(s.c_str(), "AbCdE") == 0);
assert(strcmp(s.c_str(), "abcde") != 0);
```

My idea was to make this class the same as `std::string`, and only to overwrite `operator==` :

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

struct ci_string : string {

    bool operator==(const ci_string& lhs) {
        if (this->length() != lhs.length())
            return false;
        for (size_type i = 0; i != this->length(); ++i) {
            if (tolower((*this)[i]) != tolower(lhs[i]))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

but, this code doesn't compile if you combine it with the first one, because there is no appropriate constructor of `ci_string` for `const char[]` as "AbCdE", although the parent class has one.

What is the most elegant way to solve this? I want the code to be as short as possible, without the need to rewrite string's constructors and member functions like `c_str()` etc.

Comment: You may use `basic_string` with a `char_traits` which does insensitive comparison.

Comment: Did you look at the actual solution in the book ? Or read [here](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm)

Comment: I haven't looked in the solution yet.

Comment: Shouldn't the inheritance go like `struct ci_string : public string {`? Besides that, inheritance might be the wrong approach at all.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, not unless you want to be verbose. If anything, it might be better to say `struct ci_string : private std::string`, because public inheritance is not a great idea in this case.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ public is the default.

Comment: @juanchopanza Inheritance might be a bad idea at all, as mentioned.

Comment: @Vladp THX for pointing this out, I wasn't aware [default inheritance scope behaves differently for `struct`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3811480/1413395).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more elegant way of solving the problem is using `char_traits` as shown in the answer.

But to avoid boilerplate code with your approach, you can "copy" the parent's constructors with `using string::string;` inside the child class.

Comment: What I get if I try to put `using string::string;` inside the child class is: `error C2039: 'string' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' `

Comment: Hmm, it does work on my compiler. Perhaps try to use the actual type which the `std::string` is a typedef of: `using basic_string<char>::basic_string;`

Comment: now it's `error C2886: 'basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' : symbol cannot be used in a member using-declaration`

Comment: This feature was introduced in c++11. It seems that your compiler doesn't support it yet. You'll have to define a constructor for each constructor of `std::string` and delegate them to the parent.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you define a case insensitive char traits (probably be deriving from `std::char_traits<char>` and overriding the few functions which need to be changed), there is no constructor which needed to be copied; you're still using `std::basic_string`.  (On the other hand, you _will_ need to implement the `<<` and `>>` operators and `getline`; the standard versions require the same `char_traits` for the stream and the string.)