# static_cast parent class to child class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, static-cast

Output of this program is "Method B". How can an instance of the parent object call the child class's function through a static_cast?

To make things more confusing, if I make method() virtual, then this code outputs "Method A".

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

```
class A {
public:

    void method() {
        cout << "Method A" << endl;
    }

};

class B : public A {
public:
    void method() {
        cout << "Method B" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B* bptr = static_cast<B*>(&a);
    bptr->method();
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior. You're just lucky that `cout << "Method B" << endl;` doesn't have significant side effects.

Comment: Downcasting from a parent object -> child object is always undefined behavior then? Am I understanding right?

Comment: You can do it safely using either [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) or `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @Dante Of course.  A parent is not a child so trying to making a parent a child is UB.

Comment: You should use `dynamic_cast` for downcasting

Comment: `B b;
 A* aptr = dynamic_cast<A*>(&b);
 aptr->method();`

Also why does this output "Method B" as well? How do I upcast a parent pointer to a child object so that I can call the parent method instead of the childs?

Comment: I think you might have the definitions wrong, [read this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/upcasting_downcasting.php) for clarification

Comment: @Dante You're supposed to check the results of a `dynamic_cast`. The reason _it works_ is still the same as with my introductory comment.

Comment: You **can** use static cast for downcasting, provided you have a guarantee that the actual object type is of child type (this is what CRTP does). Otherwise it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Dante it happens to work and outputs "Method B" because `B::method` doesn't access anything, it might as well be a free function. Make a member in `B` and try to do something with it in `B::method`. As `a` is not a `B` you'll probably blow up.

Comment: @Nacho Actually for a downcast (base to derived) a `static_cast` is better: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32506579/2642059 Obviously that requires the programmer to design the code so the cast will be legal... which certainly wasn't done here.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everyone. This was just an experiment for me to try to figure out how to cast properly and what the possible ways to cast are, I think I have a better understanding now.