# CRTP and downcasting

Tags: c++, crtp

Following up a similar question in [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54758272/why-is-the-downcast-in-crtp-defined-behaviour) about downcasting and  type safety , I wonder if the following example creates undefined behavior.

An instance of Base class has been created. No dynamic binding take place.
However, in the Base::interface function the instance of the  Base class is casted to an instance  of the Derived class .
Is this safe? If yes , why ?
Please find the piece of code below.

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename Derived>
struct Base{
  void interface(){
    static_cast<Derived*>(this)->implementation();
  }
};

struct Derived1: Base<Derived1>{
  void implementation(){
    std::cout << "Implementation Derived1" << std::endl;
  }
};
        
int main(){
  
  std::cout << std::endl;
  Base<Derived1> d1;
  d1.interface();
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `Derived` that this new `Derived *` could point to, so it is definitely not safe: the cast itself has undefined behaviour, as described in [expr.static.cast]§11 (emphasis mine):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`”, where `B` is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `D`”, where `D` is a complete class derived from `B`, if *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. [...] **If the prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an object of type `D`**, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type `D`. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined**.

You can mitigate this risk by restricting access to `Base`'s constructor:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct Base{
    // Same as before...

protected:
    Base() = default;
};
```

This is better, but still allows for the same issue if someone were to accidentally define `struct Derived2 : Base<AnotherDerived> { };`. Preventing that can be done with a specific `friend` declaration, but has the downside of giving full access to `Base`'s private members:

```cpp
template <typename Derived>
struct Base{
    // Same as before...

private:
    friend Derived;
    Base() = default;
};
```

Note that this still lets `Derived` construct naked `Base<Derived>` objects in its member functions, but that's where I generally stop whacking moles.

Comment: `Derived` is `Derived1`. This is the curiosity behind CRTP. Could you elaborate why you think it's UB?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I know, I'm actually quite fond of this pattern myself. However, OP's situation is that they instantiated a naked `Base<Derived1>`, *not* a `Derived1`.

Comment: Thank you, I think my brain just needed a little kick and a minute to process the relationship between the classes. Now I'm conscious of another potential pitfall to avoid, (especially seeing as everything [_looks_](https://godbolt.org/z/hrWdoW) okay, at least until it isn't).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, I think that is UB because in runtime the type of d1 is Base<Derived>.But inside the interface this is casted to a pointer of  Derived1 class

Comment: If one should speculate, since `implementation()` doesn't try to access member variables in `Derived1` the vtable lookup _seems_ to work. Had it tried accessing member variables I think a crash (or some other odd behavior) would be more likely (like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/zvhzd4)).

Comment: Most of the time with CRTP the constructors should be `protected` unless it is abstract so only derived types can be constructed. In my experience, it is rare that you can construct an instance of a CRTP base type directly.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Have a look in this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/azKdvb) . In this example a variable in Derived class is accessed. Using sanitizer , memory violation was detected

Comment: @getsoubl  It seems clang++ and g++ react differently. I used clang++ in my example. Switching to g++ made the sanitizer react.

Comment: You might want to mention you should make the `Base` ctor/dtor protected to avoid this problem.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont good point, I did just that.

Comment: Another prevention is to add a `static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<Base, Derived>);` in a method which should be instantiated (as destructor).