# Why do I get error: invalid initialization of reference of type &my_type from expression of type when using base type?

Tags: c++

In above code I am trying to write a function `do_stuff` where I will be overloading that function to handle different flavors of types derived from base type. But during my first attempt to write do_stuff I get compilation error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>


struct Base{

};

struct Item : Base{

};


void do_actual_stuff(const std::shared_ptr<Item>& item_1, const std::shared_ptr<Item>& item_2){


}

template <class T, class K>
void do_stuff(const std::shared_ptr<T>& obj1, const std::shared_ptr<K>& obj2){

  do_actual_stuff(obj1, obj2);
}


int main(){
  // std::shared_ptr<Item> item_1 {new Item()}; // works 
  //  std::shared_ptr<Item> item_2 {new Item()};  // works
  std::shared_ptr<Base> item_1 {new Item()};  // Does not work
  std::shared_ptr<Base> item_2 {new Item()};  // Does not work

  do_stuff(item_1, item_2);

}
```

Comment: Not the problem but `Base` should declare a virtual destructor.

Comment: Probably not relevant here, but `struct Item : Base` is intended, or do you want `struct Item : public Base`?

Comment: @StephanLechner That shouldn't matter; the default inheritance mode of `struct`s is `public`.

Comment: What you want to do requires a downcast ([`dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)). Compiler can't do that for you, because it doesn't know if the object actually is a `Item` at runtime.

Comment: Your code that you states works does not work for me.  Are you sure `std::shared_ptr<Base> item_2 {new Item()};  // works` works in the first case?  `std::shared_ptr<Item> item_2 {new Item()};  // works` does work.

Comment: @0x5453: thanks, found a quote in this SO answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3811480/2630032). Will leave the comment, maybe its interesting for others as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver I edited the code I had a typo.

Comment: @zett42 Is there any other way that I can achieve what I am trying to do, without using dynamic_pointer_cast? Like traits or something

Comment: But why would you pass references to shared_ptr?

Comment: Why are you expecting that to work when both template arguments are `Base`? Are you expecting the template arguments to be determined from the dynamic types of the owned objects?

Comment: @molbdnilo I guess some kind of casting is required as suggested above. But if I use dynamic_cast the whole design fall apart. So I am not sure what to do here :/

Comment: Solved the problem using dynamic_pointer_cast. Thanks @zett42.