# ‘Body2D’ is not an accessible base of ‘Hedgehog’

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have `Hedgehog` class, that inherits `Body2D` class. I want `Hedgehog` to use default `Body2D` drawing function (it's `render(SDL_Surface* )`) because it hasn't any class-specific behaviour in this case, but I've got an error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in SDLApples (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/maggistrator/Development/cpplabs/labs/Hetchehog and Apples/SDLApples/src/main.cpp||In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:|
/home/maggistrator/Development/cpplabs/labs/Hetchehog and Apples/SDLApples/src/main.cpp|84|error: ‘void Body2D::render(SDL_Surface*)’ is inaccessible within this context|
engine/include/Body2D.h|37|note: declared here|
/home/maggistrator/Development/cpplabs/labs/Hetchehog and Apples/SDLApples/src/main.cpp|84|error: ‘Body2D’ is not an accessible base of ‘Hedgehog’|
/home/maggistrator/Development/cpplabs/labs/Hetchehog and Apples/SDLApples/src/main.cpp|85|error: ‘void Body2D::render(SDL_Surface*)’ is inaccessible within this context|
engine/include/Body2D.h|37|note: declared here|
/home/maggistrator/Development/cpplabs/labs/Hetchehog and Apples/SDLApples/src/main.cpp|85|error: ‘Body2D’ is not an accessible base of ‘Apple’|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

My `Hedgehog` class is just a simple body that moves from one side of screen to another and back again. Here is it's [source code](https://pastebin.com/fZ82UBmw). `Body2D` class is abstract body in 2D world that can be drawn, updated and can interact in other bodies in the same `World`. Here is `Body2D`'s [header file](https://pastebin.com/Zyfbif14) and [source](https://pastebin.com/GA1pWGVe). And here is `main` that calls them:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
    #include <cstdlib>
#else
    #include <stdlib.h>
#endif

#include <SDL/SDL.h>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include "Hedgehog.cpp"
#include "Apple.cpp"
#include "World.h"
#include <vector>

#define APPLE_COUNT 5

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
    // initialize SDL video
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Unable to init SDL: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
        return 1;
    }
    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    // create a new window
    SDL_Surface* screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 32,
                                           SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF);
    if ( !screen )
    {
        printf("Unable to set 640x480 video: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    //OBJECTS HERE
    World scene;
    Hedgehog hg(440, 280, scene);

    std::vector<Apple> apples;
    for(int i = 0; i < APPLE_COUNT; i++)
    {
        apples.push_back(Apple(i*100, -50, scene));
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------

    // program main loop
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
        //======message processing loop======
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            // check for messages
            switch (event.type)
            {
                // exit if the window is closed
            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = true;
                break;

                // check for keypresses
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                {
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) done = true;
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RETURN) ; //Apples fall here
                    break;
                }
            } // end switch
        } //======end of message processing=====


        // UPDATE
        hg.update();
        for(Apple apple: apples) apple.update();

        // RENDER
        SDL_FillRect(screen, 0, SDL_MapRGB(screen->format, 0, 0, 0));
        hg.render(screen);
        for(Apple apple: apples) apple.render(screen);

        SDL_Flip(screen);
    } // end main loop

    printf("Exited cleanly\n");
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is: can I use base class's function without overriding it? Or default behaviour is allowed only for objects of base class itself?

p.s. I was learning Java for several years, but now I have to use C++, so may be I'm making some common Java-programmer's mistake in understanding language vision of inheritance?

Comment: One quick thing to be careful of is that if you just have a variable, by itself, such as `Apple apple`, then that variable has its own copy of its data.  It is _not_ a reference into `apples`.  Just make sure to use `Apple const& apple` or `Apple & apple` (depending on whether you intend to keep `apple` constant or modify it).  Or `auto&& apple` if you're feeling lazy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Default class inheritance access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811424/default-class-inheritance-access)

Comment: For the future: if the compiler gives you an error I can guarantee you that somebody else has had the same problem. Google it!

Comment: @hegel5000 thanks, it's important notice, I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: @vasek straight answer without comparsions with structures is clearer, but it's useful as expanded explanation, so thanks for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you have to use access modifier when inheriting from base class, otherwise `private` inheritance is assumed by default for classes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3811441/611117). So your code should be fixed by inheriting using `public` modifier:

```
class Hedgehog : public Body2D
```

There is no similar principle in Java, `extends` keyword can not change access modifiers.