# trying to use inheritance but unable to access parent class

Tags: c++, inheritance

hello i am trying to create a class that uses inheritance from class Student to class Graduate Student but program says it is inaccessible.

```
    class Student
{
    Student(char* n, int id)
    {
        name = new char[strlen(n) + 1];
        strcpy_s(name,strlen(n)+1, n);
        studentId = id;
    }
    ~Student()
    {
        if (name != NULL)
            delete[]name;
    }
    void printStudent()
    {
        cout << "Student ID: " << studentId << "\nStudent Name: " << name << endl;
    }
protected:
    int studentId;
    char* name;
};
```

```
class GraduateStudent :public Student
{
public:
    GraduateStudent(char* n, char* a, int id) : Student(n, id)
    {
        area = new char[strlen(a) + 1];
        strcpy_s(area, strlen(a) + 1, a);
    }
    ~GraduateStudent()
    {
        if (area != NULL)
            delete[]area;
    }
    void printGrad()
    {
        printStudent();
        cout << "Research area: " << area << endl;
    }
private:
    char* area;
};
```

the program is supposed to print out an initiallised GraduateStudent class variable be calling printStudent();

Comment: you forgot to add `public:` at the top of `Student` class, by default access level for class is private (for struct its public so you could alternatively make `Student` a struct)

Comment: offtopic: have mercy: `name = new char[strlen(n) + 1]` for anyone (yourself) who will read this code. Just use `std::string`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't have to test for a null pointer before deleting it. `delete[]area;` will work just fine, even if `area` is null. Further, given the code above, `area` won't ever be null, so the test is doubly pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Default access for a class is private, which makes OP's functions private.
So, your constructor is private.
You should read [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm).
Also, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811424/default-class-inheritance-access) answer your question?

thx for edits @sweenish

Answer (score 0):

You declared `int studentId;` and `char* name;` as protected, so in `GraduateStudent` you can access them, so you can easily do:

```cpp
void printGrad() {
  cout << "Student ID: " << studentId << "\nStudent Name: " << name << endl;
  cout << "Research area: " << area << endl;
}
```

or, alternatively, declare `printStudent();` in the `public` part of `Student`. In fact, if you declare something without any kind of specification, in a `class`, it is `private` by default, while in a `struct`, it is `public`.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating your classes, you may define `access modifiers` or `access specifiers`.(https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) (These are those words such as `public`, `private` or `protected` in your class).  You may find [doc here]

```cpp
class myClass{ 
   public:
      // public members go here
   protected:
      // protected members go here
   private:
      // private members go here
};
```

To make it simple, they allow you to tell whether a member should be accessible from everywhere, from derived classes only or not at all from outside the class where it is defined. When you do not put anything, in a `C++` class,  it means that it is `private` by default.

Thus your `printStudent()` method is private and cannot be accessed from your `GraduateStudent` class.

A good starting point for more details and more understanding of the notion is to read some [tutorials](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-in-c/)

To solve your compilation problem, you should make your `Student` constructor, destructor and `printStudent` as public to allow the derived class to access them and compile.

```cpp
class Student
{
 public:
    Student(char* n, int id)
    {
      ...
    }
    ~Student()
    {
      ...
    }

    void printStudent()
    {
      ...
    }
....
};
```